# Updating MySQL table using Python loop and escape

Tags: python, mysql-connector

I wrote a python script to update currency exchange rates using API calls. I successfully parsed the json results and extracted individual exchange rates as floats. I am however struggling with formatting/implementing an SQL table update loop.

Here is a code snippet that is tripping me up, assume that val = an actual exchange rate variable that is supplied from the API fetching/parsing section of the code:

```
            mycursor = mydb.cursor()
            sql = "UPDATE currencies SET coefficient = %s"
            val = 0.03137
            mycursor.execute(sql, val)
            mydb.commit()
```

Running this gives me the following error:

`Could not process parameters: float(0.03137), it must be of type list, tuple or dict:`

I do not even know what to search for in order to reach an explanation that I understand and that helps me implement what I want correctly.

Answer (score 0):

From: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-api-mysqlcursor-execute.html

> Note
>
> In Python, a tuple containing a single value must include a comma. For
> example, ('abc') is evaluated as a scalar while ('abc',) is evaluated
> as a tuple.

Thus in my example the expression that works is:

`val = (0.03137, )`